# Prove $f(x_0) = x_0$ iff $f'(1) > 1$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f: [0, 1] \to \mathbb{R}$ be two times differentiable and $f''(x) > 0$ for all $x \in [0, 1]$. Moreover $f(0) > 0$ and $f(1) = 1$. Prove that there exists $x_0 \in (0, 1)$ such that $f(x_0) = x_0$ if and only if $f'(1) > 1$.

Intuitively it's obvious by making a simple drawing, because $f''(x) > 0$ implies $f$ is convex and $f'(1) > 1$ makes slopes of tangents steep, but I have no idea how to prove it formally.

Comment: Consider $g(x) = f(x)-x$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider $g(x) = f(x)-x$ as suggested by marty cohen. Then $g''>0$, $g(0) > 0$, and $g(1) = 0$. We have to prove that $g$ has a zero in $(0,1)$ iff $g'(1) > 0$.

Assume $g'(1)>0$. As $g(1) = 0$, we have $g(1-\varepsilon) < 0$ for small $\varepsilon > 0$. Since $g(0) > 0$, there is a zero of $g$ in $(0,1-\varepsilon)$ by the IVT.

Assume $g(c) = 0$ for some $c\in (0,1)$. By Rolle's theorem, there is $d\in (c,1)$ such that $g'(d) = 0$. And as (due to $g''>0$) $g'$ is strictly increasing, it follows that $g'(1) > 0$.

Answer (score 2):

You get one way using the comment by Marty Cohen.For the converse suppose $f'(1-) \leq 1$. Since $f''>0$ it follows that $f'$ is strictly increasing. Hence $f'(x) <1$ for all $x <1$. Now apply MVT to $f(1)-f(x_0)$ to get a contradiction.